# Returning an error message for input type time

Tags: javascript, html, validation, time

This is my code part for the input type time in my html formincluding its validation

```
<tr><td height="50"><div class="headingbox" id="hBoxTime" >Expected Time </div>
            <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <input type="time" id=time  autofocus name=DPTime   onfocusout="upperCASE(this);validateTime(this, 'timeerror')" onfocus="show('timeerror2');" min="08:00:00" max="16:00:00" onblur="onTimeChange()" /><br>
            </div>

               <div class="error" id="timeerror" > error occured </div><br>
     <script>
var input =  document.getElementById('time');
function validateTime (element,errorCode) {

var minTime = element.min;
var maxTime = element.max
var value = element.value + ':00'
var notify = document.getElementById(errorCODE);
console.log(minTime,maxTime,value);
if(minTime > value ||  value > maxTime) {
  notify.innerHTML = "Enter between 8am and 4pm";
            element.style.border = "2px solid #ff6768";
            notify.style.opacity="1";
            timeValid = false;
            headingBoxAlert("hBoxTime", timeValid);
}

}



</script>
```

This is my html code for the input type email along with its validation code in Javascript

```
  <tr><td height="50"><div class="headingbox" id="hBoxEM"> E-mail </div>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <input type="text"  autofocus name=Email onfocus="headingBoxActive('hBoxEM')" onfocusout="validateEmail(this, 'emailerror');"  /><br>
                </div>
                <div class="error" id="emailerror" > error occured </div><br>
<script>
                 function validateEmail(element, errorCODE){
        var str = element.value;
        var dotCount = 0;
        var atCount = 0;
        var notify = document.getElementById(errorCODE);
        if(str.length==0) {
            notify.innerHTML = "Email must be specified";
            element.style.border = "2px solid #ff6768";
            notify.style.opacity="1";
            emailValid = false;
            headingBoxAlert('hBoxEM', emailValid);
        }
        else if(str.length<6){
            notify.innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
            element.style.border = "2px solid #ff6768";
            notify.style.opacity="1";
            emailValid = true;
            headingBoxAlert('hBoxEM', emailValid);
        }
</script>
```

Though the validation for email displays an error for email no error is shown for the time if i enter a value not between 8am and 4pm please help me to rectify it! [image]

Comment: Your `if(minTime > value ||  value > maxTime)` condition doesn't seems to be checking the time between `8am - 4pm` ?

Comment: @DavidR Seems fine to me. I'd assume the issue is that you're doing comparisons on the times using `<` and `>`, however `value`, `min,` and `max`, are *strings*. If you're comparing numbers as strings, 16 > 8 will return `false`, etc, because it's doing the comparison alphanumerically. **EDIT:** Actually, I think the problem may be unrelated. I'll answer below.

Comment: so please correct my code will you its very difficult to tackle this it works with alert box

Comment: I'd suggest checking your console (by pressing F12) for Javascript errors.


I've simplified your code at this JSFiddle and it seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dekp56xu/